# Creating a CSS triangle with true transparent background

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal menu composed as an un-ordered list, each list item is a link and there are special expanding list items that are, well, expandable (they open up a new vertical style menu). I want to have the menu background transparent black, and with a white border along the bottom. I also want the expandable list items to have a bottom arrow sticking out. Unfortunately setting the outer triangle to be white and the inner triangle to transparent black shows the white triangle underneath. Is there any way of getting a truly transparent inner triangle such that the menu could be placed on a background image or texture?

http://jsfiddle.net/RMCtk/2/

HTML:

```
<body>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="expand"><a href="#">Product</a>
                           <ul>
                               <li><a href="#">pro1</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">pro2</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">pro3</a></li>
                           </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">lalalalalalala</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pickles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    top:50px;
    line-height:20px;
    font-size:20px;
    width:calc(6*150px);
    height:auto;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    nav ul {
    margin:0;padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    }
    nav ul li {
    border:1px solid blue;
    border-right:none;border-top:none;border-left:none;
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    background-color:white;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    nav ul li a {
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    padding:5px 0;
    text-align:center;
    }
    nav ul li:hover {
    background:orange;
    }
    nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
    }
    nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:-450px+900px; /*margin-left + width of #nav*/
    top:30px;
    width:150px;
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
    color:black;
    font-family:Arial;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
    li.expand:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    height:0; 
    width:0;
    border-left:15px solid transparent;  /* left arrow slant */
    border-right:15px solid transparent; /* right arrow slant */
    border-top:15px solid blue; /*bg color here*/
    margin-left:60px; /*75-15*/
    margin-top:29px;
    }
    li.expand:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    height:0; 
    width:0;
    border-left:14px solid transparent;  /* left arrow slant */
    border-right:14px solid transparent; /* right arrow slant */
    border-top:14px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /*bg color here*/
    margin-left:60.5px;
    }
    li.expand:hover:after,li.expand:hover:before {
    display:none;
    }
```

As you can see in the example, the border is blue, the background should be TRANSPARENT, and NOT WHITE. White would match the background of jsfiddle content box giving the illusion of transparency, but not true transparency. If this cannot be done, can anyone suggest a 'proper' way I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

The trick you have used to create the triangle is by manipulating the border widths. The arrow **is** a border - you can't set a border color on that (if i understand what you meant correctly).

Comment: No, but what I have done here is create a larger triangle below a smaller triangle. In this way the larger triangle forms the "border" of the smaller embedded triangle, and the smaller triangle creates a 'background' for the larger triangle